# ExoPlayer - How to know if HLS video is Live or not?

Tags: android, events, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

I'm developing a video application when an HLS video starts as Live but after the .m3u8 playlist has completed loading we want to move back to seeing VOD HLS instead of Live.

How can I tell if HLS video is in Live mode and changed to VOD ?

Comment: Have got the solution for the same? I am also looking for the same in exoplayer to know whether the HLS video is LIVE or VOD or EVENT.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `mExoPlayer.isCurrentWindowDynamic()` [link](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/SimpleExoPlayer.html#isCurrentWindowDynamic--)

so in the code you will use it like this:

```
    if (mExoPlayer.isCurrentWindowDynamic()) {
        // treat me as live stream
    } else {
        // treat me as VOD (Video On Demand)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried for detecting the HLS video is Live or VOD. We can able to differentiate a live stream from a VOD by getting the player's duration after it is prepared. The live streams will return UNKNOWN_TIME, where as VOD streams will return the fixed known duration of the stream which is currently playing.

Comment: I used the same method but it seems to be broken with newer releases. We upgraded from 2.0.4 to 2.1.1 and exoplayer now returns 60s as duration for a stream source!

Comment: Yes @Altoyyr, In new release of exoplayer the functionality of the DVR with live has been proposed. If the current release will come in stable channel then it will available.